# How to render a map with bounds which are saved on zoomend function in leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I have to save the Zoom level of the Map. In zoom end function of Map I saved it in a local storage and while again the component is rendered, I tried to check whether any zoom value is preserved or not. Based on it I tried to render the Map.Everythings works fine but I need to save the location also so I tried to get the bounds and do the same as in Zoom level.It's not working I tried to apply fitBounds if there is any value in local storage. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
    initializeMap = () => {
      const { user } = this.props;
      const zoomLevel = localStorage.getItem('itemsZoom');
      let boundCoordinates = {};
      boundCoordinates = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsBounds'));
      if (zoomLevel !== null && Object.keys(boundCoordinates).length > 0) {
        this.map.fitbounds(boundCoordinates);
      }
      this.map.fitbounds(boundCoordinates);

     this.map = L.map('map', {
      center: [38.778, -73.554]
      zoom: zoomLevel !== null ? zoomLevel : 18
    });
     L.gridLayer.googleMutant({ type: 'satellite', maxZoom: 20 }).addTo(this.map);

     this.map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, (e) => {
      this.onMarkerCreated(e);
    });

    this.map.on('draw:editmove', (e) => {
      this.onMarkerEdited(e);
    });


    this.map.on('zoomend', (e) => {
      const zoom = this.map.getZoom();
      localStorage.setItem('itemsZoom', zoom);
      const bounds = this.map.getBounds();
      localStorage.setItem('itemsBounds', JSON.stringify(bounds));
    });
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this to save the bounds `localStorage.setItem('itemsBounds',this.map.getBounds().toBBoxString()))` and then when you read out call:

```
[west, south, east, north] = localStorage.getItem('itemsBounds').split(',').map(parseFloat)
var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(new L.LatLng(south, west), new L.LatLng(north, east))
this.map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

PS: `fitBounds` with "B"

Comment: Thanks for your response, I followed the same I am getting an error of fitBounds undefined.When I console bounds Iam getting this value {"_southWest":{"lat":40.63115119323159,"lng":-73.8413429260254},"_northEast":{"lat":40.65062473460171,"lng":-73.67697715759279}}

Comment: aah I know why. You are useing `this.map` before `this.map` is initialized. Put `this.map.fitBounds(bounds);` below `this.map = L.map('map', { ...`

Comment: thanks for your help. It worked exactly the way I needed it.